# Is it notational practice to use floor and ceiling division to partition an array in math proofs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms

In the DPV algorithm book I see an array split like so:

$x_L, x_R$ = leftmost  $\lceil n/2 \rceil $, rightmost $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$

This is not something I have seen before as in the odd case you have 1 to k, k+1 to n but in the even case you have 1 to k, k to n.

Comment: No, if $n=2k$, the first $k$ are $x_1,\ldots,x_k$, and the last $k$ are $x_{k+1},\ldots,x_{2k}$. If $n=2k+1$, $x_L$ contains $x_1,\ldots,x_{k+1}$, and $x_R$ contains $x_{k+2},\ldots,x_{2k+1}$.

Comment: I'm a programmer maybe the definition is different. e.g. floor(6) = 3, ceil(6) = 3?

Comment: I assume that you meant that the floor and ceiling of $6/2$ are both $3$. That’s correct. And the leftmost $3$ elements of a list of $6$ are $x_1,x_2$, and $x_3$, while the rightmost $3$ are $x_4,x_5$, and $x_6$. Note that the latter do not start at $x_3$, but at  $x_{3+1}$.

Comment: okay that's how to read it thank you.

Comment: You’re welcome.